# Pseudocode for class project

Tags: java

I'm writing Pseudocode for a project for class and I feel like i'm missing some things

Here is what the project requires

As a zookeeper, it is important to know the activities of the animals in your care and to monitor their living habitats. Create a monitoring system that does all of the following:

 Asks a user if they want to monitor an animal, monitor a habitat, or exit  Displays a list of animal/habitat options (based on the previous selection) as read from either the animals or habitats file

o Asks the user to enter one of the options  Displays the monitoring information by finding the appropriate section in the file   Separates sections by the category and selection (such as “Animal - Lion” or “Habitat - Penguin”)  Uses a dialog box to alert the zookeeper if the monitor detects something out of the normal range (These will be denoted in the files by a new line starting with *****. Do not display the asterisks in the dialog.)  Allows a user to return to the original options

and here is what I've wrote

```
function MonitoringSystem(): 
    OBTAIN animal or habitat 

        IF animal 
        PRINT list of animal options 
        OBTAIN option from the user 
        PRINT selection by the user 
        PRINT alert if available
```

IF habitat 
            PRINT list of habitat options 
            OBTAIN option from the user 
            PRINT selection by the user 
           PRINT alert if available 
        ELSE exit the program 
    ENDIF 
 
  Am I missing anything? I feel like I am, any suggestions would be helpful Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - based off the criteria you should add the following at a minimum:

```
function MonitoringSystem(): 

    OBTAIN animal or habitat 

    IF animal 
    PRINT list of animal options (and option to go back)
    OBTAIN option from the user 
    PRINT selection by the user // It doesn't say to do this
    PRINT alert if available

    ELSE IF habitat
    PRINT list of habitat options (and option to go back)
    OBTAIN option from the user
    PRINT alert if available

    ELSE exit program
```

Also, it's not very specific on whether or not this needs to be continuous. If it is you want to nest all of this inside a while loop dependent upon the user entering exit.